# Tab indents in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have little problem with intends, I push the tab in HTML and VSC adding here not one intends in a new line but it multiplies one indent by 4(so one indent is made from 4spaces) and in result are 16spaces as 4 indents but not one indent as I expected. Have you any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @Scath Why, what does `Ctrl+K C` do? (In my VSCode, it does nothing and official (Win) hotkey list doesn't mention it either.)

Comment: @Konrad Siczek Are you using the latest version? Do you have any plugins?

Comment: @juzraai I use the latest version, and  I have uninstalled all plugins that can format code. (Mac user)

Comment: I just tried it but still, it not works. For now, I use "CMD + }", but it isn't a solution.